# Why webkit2webprocess.exe stop in safari?

Tags: safari

I am testing my website in all browser, and suddenly I encounter this problem in safari browser version 5.1.7. The app crashes and there is always a popup which as shown below when I clicked to another link on my website.  I am using windows 7 OS. Why is this happening? Is this because of my code?

[image]

Any answer is very much appreciated.

Comment: Safari on Windows always was a bit buggy, so a crash isn't surprising. Can you repeat the error doing the same thing every time or is it just "flaky"?

Comment: The error always display everytime. I also tried it now in safari with mac OS, it also crashes.

Comment: I am also getting same issue while having large amount of data in Drop Down and when click on Dropdown i am getting same. If you got any solution please let me know.

Comment: I already solve mine sir. The problem is on my javascript, i just modify the script and boom, magic happens.